# GTM and Analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Whenever I setup Universal Google Analytics tag (like pageview) then GTM injects the analytics.js on my source code? Or will it use a built-in function to send tracking info to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will inject *analytics.js* along with *gtm.js*. You may find [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6163791?hl=en)  guide on installing Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager helpful.